# Virtual Keyboard Closing Automatically

Tags: android, jquery, ios, angularjs, cordova

Hi I am writing a cordova app using AngularJS. If I include JQuery in the app, I get the 300 ms input delay. But if I don't include JQuery in the app when I tap on an input or a text field, the virtual keyboard doesn't pop up(I think it shows itself for a brief second then dismisses itself). This is happening on both iOS and Android.

I am using ngTouch and the Angular Bootstrap, but either of those don't appear to be the issue.

Thanks, Krtko

Comment: i guess its ngTouch issue. Try commenting event.target && event.target.blur() & tapElement.blur(); in angular file

Comment: Awesome I commented out line 354 and it appears to have the desired results.

Comment: Odd tho now if I click again on the input element it will close the keyboard rather than just moving the cursor.